# Drupal JS add noscript after every <script> tag

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to add the noscript tag after every  tag. Even the file tags. I cannot have alternatives as the client I'm doing this for has made this mandatory for 508 purposes. I believe the software they are using is failing the 508 scan because of this.

Example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://local.dev/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support Javascript</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://local.dev/misc/drupal.js?neolt5"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support Javascript</noscript>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the html.tpl.php of your theme to add the noscript tag using the $scripts array.

```
$scripts = str_replace("\n", "\n<noscript>Your browser does not support Javascript</noscript>\n", $scripts);
```

Note : html.tpl.php will apply this for all pages of your theme.if you want to do it for specific content type pages or specific pages then use the specific template.See [Drupal 7 template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) for more information.